# Remove previous glow of the shape and add a new glow with VBA in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am facing a minor issue in VBA PowerPoint that is i want to change the glow effect with help of VBA but for some reason its not working . if i try to add glow without removing previous one it adds it on top of previous effect
i have tried to change glow radius but it is not getting updated for some reason

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Glow.Radius = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i figured out when you are using grouped shapes the glow is added to topmost shape when you add it manually and it is non editable while if you are adding glow with vba it is added to bottommost shape and can be removed with vba